# Show or movie by Cartoon Network where monsters from a game (presumably World of Warcraft) come to life

Tags: story-identification, tv

There was a show I would watch sometimes when I was young, around 2014/2015.

The main characters play a game and, one day, the monsters from that game come to life and they have to fight them.

The show is live-action and was aired on Cartoon Network.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It has to be [Level Up](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_Up_(American_TV_series)) (2012–2013), since it's one of the few live action Cartoon Network shows:

> After high schoolers Wyatt, Lyle, Dante and Angie unwittingly open a portal from a video game called Maldark: Conqueror of All Worlds into the real world, characters from the game and the Internet start leaking into the real world of the four teenage characters. The group consequently finds itself balancing its members' everyday lives with the extraordinary things that show up in their town from the virtual world which always resorts to using NeverFail to help send the monsters back into the game by "barding" them.

Comment: Bingo! that's it, brings back a ton of nostalgia!